# resolve: Host not found (authoritative), while using http_listener() of CPPrest sdk

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, cpprest-sdk

below is the piece of server side code, written in c++:

```
utility::string_t port = U("8080");
utility::string_t address = U("http://service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-http.ricxapp:");
address.append(port);
address.append(U("/ric/v1/subscriptions/response"));
uri_builder uri(address);
auto addr = uri.to_uri().to_string();
http_listener listener(addr);
cout<<uri::validate(addr)<<"\n"; //--------> this is printing 1
```

I am running this piece of code in Ubuntu 18

Comment: What is you question? A bit more description of your issue could help as well. (Please, have a look onto [ask] and it couldn't hurt to take the [tour].)

Comment: is `service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-http.ricxapp` the hostname of the machine that you are running this code on? If not then it's probably not the right URL to pass when creating a listener

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.